# GoJS unable to read data from toJson

Tags: gojs

Following is the Json String produced by calling method toJson on my model :

currentString= 
{ \"class\": \"go.TreeModel\",\n \"nodeDataArray\": [ \n{\"key\":0, \"text\":\"Mind Map\", \"loc\":\"0 0\"},\n{\"text\":\"idea\", \"parent\":0, \"key\":-2, \"loc\":\"78.22705078125 0\"},\n{\"text\":\"idea\", \"parent\":-2, \"key\":-3, \"loc\":\"128.22705078125 0\"}\n ]}

Now when i try to load data from this string using :
myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(currentString);

Nothing happens at all whereas when I try to load a normal model , it works.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The String was getting changed most probably on the server side and Go js was not reading it as a valid String , hence I removed the invalid characters to make it a valid Json String via the below code. Also, there were some extra quotes at the beginning and end. After this, it worked perfectly.

```
    String trimCurrentString=currentString.replaceAll("\\\\n", " ");//removes /n from the string.
                String doubletrimCurrentString=trimCurrentString.replaceAll("\\\\","");//removes \from the  String.
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(doubletrimCurrentString);
                stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);//removes the quote from beginning
                stringBuilder.deleteCharAt((stringBuilder.length())-1);//removes the quote from the end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `currentString` needs to be a string, not a JavaScript Object.

Second, you need to stop using backslash before each double-quote.

Comment: CurrentString was saved as a string by GoJs but maybe it changed when i uploaded or downloaded it from the Firebase server and this is what i recieved.                                                                                                           Currentstring was returned as is in this format only. Thanks for your help Walter , I was able to solve it by editing this string/object to the required format by removing the \ and \n and it worked perfectly.